# jQuery Function is not Waiting for the Whole Page to Load Before Running

Tags: jquery, html, css, facebook-graph-api

I am dynamically generating a div's height in accordance to the height of a second div. #admin_table_2 is generating a table and I want the height of that to be the same as the height of the div that it's contained within. The issue is that I'm querying the Facebook graph so it takes a minute as it lays out the table. Basically, the jQuery function grabs the height of #admin_table_2 before it's completely finished loading so while the div may be 1000px tall, it'll generate the height of the bigger div as "236px" for example since it grabs the value before the div finishes loading. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$("#left").css({'height':($("#admin_table_2").height()+'px')});
});
```

It's doing the correct thing, it's just not waiting until the document has completely finished loading. I'm assuming the document actually is finished loading but the Facebook Graph takes longer than the page. Any ideas on how to wait until the Graph query is done before generating the height? Thanks!

Comment: Try using the window load event instead, it waits until all css and images are done loading.

Comment: qq: why use JS? that said: how are you making the graph request? there must be a callback? why can't you perform this operation in there when you're ready to do so?

Comment: The graph request is being done as a while loop. In my MySQL database, I've got a row for Facebook IDs and then the while loop queries the database and uses the Facebook ID to display the profile pictures of the users like so: http://graph.facebook.com/".$fb_id."/picture/ . So it takes a second for them to all load because they aren't being pulled from my database but from the graph. Does that make sense? I'm sure there's a simpler way than I'm doing it...

Comment: @KevinB, window load worked perfect for what I'm doing. If you put it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to wait until the page is done loading, use the window's load event. the document ready event can trigger a good while before the load event depending on the number and size of assets.